# Action in a DATABASE with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have an error when i try to connect my database.

```
Error : SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

I doubt it was the `ID` but with phpMyAdmin I put it AUTOINCREMENT ...

Here's my code -->

From the DATABASE ON PHPMYADMIN

```
CREATE TABLE  `Compte_Utilisateur`.`info_compte` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`username` VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,
`suffixe` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,
`siteWeb` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`fonction` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

And from my file php --> I want to ADD a User to the DATABASE (But YOU ALL ALREADY KNOW :D)

```
<?php
$username = $_POST["username"];
$suffixe = $_POST["suffixe"];
$passwd = $_POST["password"];
$site = $_POST["site"];
$fonction = $_POST["fonction"];

try
{
    $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=compte_utilisateur', 'root', '', $pdo_options);

    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO info_compte(username, suffixe, password, siteWeb, fonction) 
                            VALUES(:username, :suffixe, :passwd, :site, :fonction)');
    $req->execute(array(
    'username' => $username,
    'suffixe' => $suffixe,
    'password' => $passwd,
    'siteWeb' => $site,
    'fonction' => $fonction,
    ));
    echo 'Compte ajouté avec succès';
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Thanks to answer !

Comment: Have you tried replacing 'username' => $username with ':username' => $username etc. yet?

Comment: @teuneboon: i ll try it now.. i hope it wasn't stupid like that (novice error)

Comment: @teuneboon: I even got the error even if i change 'username' etc.. to ':username' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your binders matching? "username", "suffixe" and "fonction" look good but "password" and "siteWeb" look off. Your prepare shows "passwd" and "site" but you're using "password" and "siteWeb" as your binding keys.

```
$req->execute(array(
    'username' => $username,
    'suffixe' => $suffixe,
    'passwd' => $passwd,
    'site' => $site,
    'fonction' => $fonction));
```

Comment: "password" and "siteWeb" are the element of my database table. And "$passwd" and "site" are variable that i'm taken from a <Form>

Comment: Your prepare statement has this... ":username, :suffixe, :passwd, :site, :fonction". Those need to be the keys passed in your array when you call the execute() method. They don't match so you're passing empty/null values.

Comment: Oh wait ... i think i see what you're saying ..wait --> i'm testing

Comment: You are right .. THANKS FOR ALL THE ANSWERS EVERYBODY especially INKSPEAK & BW_ÜEZI

Answer (score 1):

(no php here to test...)

remove the last comma in the execute array:

```
$req->execute(array(
'username' => $username,
'suffixe' => $suffixe,
'password' => $passwd,
'siteWeb' => $site,
'fonction' => $fonction        // <-- no comma here... 
));
```

or your array will include an additional null element and thus be too large.

Comment: i correct it => for this you are right
But i got the same error again

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that mysql doesn't support named parameters in the prepared sql. 
use `?` instead of `:name` (and also remove these names form the array)

update: looks like this is not a problem with a PDO driver (I'm more familiar with JDBC drivers...)

Comment: it suppose to works.. i've done it before on another prodject with the same server and the same tools